# Modifying MySQL statement to filter data on an interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a working MySQL statement (using mysql workbench) that is being used to source data from one schema and insert it into a specific table/format in another schema (First schema is read-only).

Quick description: This is logging call data and call time for CSR agents that needs to aggregate throughout the day.

The format is correct and the statement inserts the data properly but I need to modify things a bit to fit certain parameters. The way it runs now, it just inserts every time (the goal is to make this an event for every 15 minutes) but it may duplicate for certain extensions.

I need this, when it's run every 15 minutes, to say "If the extension/extension ID already exists, add the new data onto the existing data, otherwise create a new record for this extension". This way, if agent 1 works all day they may add call minutes throughout the day, but agent 2 may work half a day and only add on for those hours.

The existing query:

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(ExtID, Extension, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, Missed_Calls, Total_Calls)  
SELECT 
RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
, c.extension as Extension
, sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inbound
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
, count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
  FROM cdrdb.session a
  JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
   ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
     join cdrdb.mxuser c
      ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      -- WHERE b.ts > (now() - interval 15 minute)
  GROUP BY a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
  ORDER BY Total_Talk_Time_minutes DESC
```

I commented out the line that only pulls from the last 15 minutes, but that just simulates the job time and it only pulls the latest data, whereas I need it to add up the latest data in real time and I'll set it to just run every 15 minutes.

HOw can I modify this to update the existing Extensions and add any new ones, only for the current day?

To clarify, if there is an option, I'd like to keep the end of day totals from each day, and just start new inserts every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, then below one will solve your problem.

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(ExtID, Extension, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, Missed_Calls, Total_Calls)  
    select * from (SELECT 
    RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
    , c.extension as Extension
    , sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
    , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inbound
    , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
    , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
      FROM cdrdb.session a
      JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
       ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
         join cdrdb.mxuser c
          ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
          -- WHERE b.ts > (now() - interval 15 minute)
      GROUP BY a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
      ORDER BY Total_Talk_Time_minutes DESC) as tmp where (ExtID, Extension) not in (select ExtID, Extension from test.ambition_test)
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry if I didn't make sense in all the right spots. This does seem to add anyone who isn't already in the table, but I want to be able to do this so that if their extension is already in the table from the last job 15 minutes ago, it will update the table for them with their new totals in addition to those new records.